# How do I rename rasters in an mxd by using my csv?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, csv, arcpy

I have the following data in a csv:

```
    RasterName  First name
    Raster 1    Aaron
    Raster 1    Paul
    Raster 2    Bryan
    Raster 3    Cranston
    Raster 3    Vince
```

I have added these rasters to my mxd as many times as necessary (twice for Raster 1, once for Raster 2 and twice for Raster 3), so that my TOC looks like the `RasterName` column.  Now I need to rename the raster in my map document to the appropriate `First name`.  I read the csv into csvdict using reader and when I use the following:

```
csvdict = []
for row in reader:
        csvdict.append(row)

for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):  
    for i,j in csvdict:
        if layer.name == i:
            layer.name = j
```

I get this:

```
    Aaron
    Aaron
    Bryan
    Cranston
    Cranston
```

When I really want:

```
    Aaron
    Paul
    Bryan
    Cranston
    Vince
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: what is the variable 'lyr' assigned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try popping from your csvdict list after using a row to rename a raster:

```
     for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):  
         for i in range(len(csvdict)):
             if layer.name == csvdict[i][0]:
                 layer.name = csvdict[i][1]
                 csvdict.pop(i)
                 break
```